# How to insert multiple expression in single interpolation angular2

Tags: angular, templates, syntax

How to insert multiple expression in single interpolation in angular 2, for example like this:

```
{{ title + !isLast ? ' > ' : ''}}
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for your requirement will be -

```
<span *ngFor="let item of listOne; let isLast = last">
          {{getItem(item, isLast)}}
</span>
```

in your template and implement getter in your component

```
getItem(item: string, isLast: boolean) {
    return `${item} ${isLast ? '>' : ''}`;
  }
```

Basically when you have complex manipulations use getter to get value after manipulations

Comment: Using the function in a template it is not the best approach, this function will be executed every change detection tick (). That will entail memory leaks.

Comment: @SobolRoman yes, the best way is using custom pipe instead of calling functions from template.

Answer (score 1):

This particular case could be achieved with CSS [`after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) (and with `last` and `:not()`)

If you really want nested ternary expressions, just use `()` where approperiate.

Consider using a `get xxx(): string {}` getter in your TypeScript so the logic remains more readable.

Finally, don't forget about npm packages like [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) which may make things simpler if you want to display text.